# SenticoSansDT - Medium and thin not loading in xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, uifont

I tried to load the following fonts

```
SenticoSansDT - Light
SenticoSansDT - Regular
SenticoSansDT - Thin
SenticoSansDT - Medium
```

all are font file with extension .ttf

i added to Xcode and check the target. added the fonts in build phase as well as info.plist. but i'm seeing only the Regular and Light font to be enabled. Medium is not showing in Font book and also in story board

Comment: Did you try cleaning the build before running?

Comment: Thanks for the comment. Yes i tried that many times.

Comment: Ok.  Did you check each file to ensure that it has Target Membership so that it is truly copied into the project?  To check, select the file and show the file inspector, there you can check and ensure that it is/or isn't added to the proper target.

Comment: Can you attach font files in your post, as this fonts are not available for free download.

Answer (score 3):

Install the .ttf file on mac and use this below code to find the exact name of the font.

```
NSArray *familyNames = [[NSArray alloc] initWithArray:[UIFont familyNames]];
NSArray *fontNames;
NSInteger indFamily, indFont;
NSInteger fontsCount = [familyNames count];

for (indFamily = 0; indFamily < fontsCount; ++indFamily) {
    NSLog (@"Family name: %@", [familyNames objectAtIndex:indFamily]);
    fontNames = [[NSArray alloc] initWithArray:[UIFont fontNamesForFamilyName:[familyNames objectAtIndex:indFamily]]];
    for (indFont = 0; indFont < [fontNames count]; ++indFont) {
        NSLog (@"Font name: %@", [fontNames objectAtIndex:indFont]);
    }

}
```

Use the Font name of "SenticoSansDT Medium and Thin" printed on the log.